# Find the b and power value in the binomial with the given expansion of the first 3 terms

Tags: binomial-theorem

In the expansion of $\left ( 1 + x \right )^{n}$, the first three terms are 1 - 0.9 + 0.36. Find the values of x and n.

I'm clueless as to how I would solve this......

Answer (score 2):

The firts three terms are:
$\quad(1+x)^n=1+nx+\dfrac{n(n-1)}2\,x^2=1-0.9+0.36$,  so we have 
$$\begin{cases}nx=-0.9\\n(n-1)x^2=0.72\end{cases}$$
The second equation can be rewritten as $
$$(nx)^2-nx^2=0.81-nx^2=0.72$, so $nx^2=0.09$, from which we deduce
$$x=\frac{nx^2}{nx}=-0.1,\;\text{ whence }\;n=9.$$

Comment: Slightly simpler: divide the second by the first to get $(n-1)x = -.8$. Subtracting this from the first, $x = -.1$.

Answer (score 1):

Generalizing Bernard's answer:

If
$(1+x)^n = 1+a+b$,
then
$nx =a$
and
$n(n-1)x^2/2 = b$.

Dividing the
second equation
by the first,
$(n-1)x/2 = b/a$
or
$(n-1)x = 2b/a$.

Subtracting this
from the first,
$x = a-2b/a
=(a^2-2b)/a
$
and
$n
= a/x
=a/((a^2-2b)/a)
=a^2/(a^2-2b)
=1/(1-2b/a^2)
$.

Check.

If
$a=-.9$ and $b=.36$,
then
$x
=-.9-(.72/-.9)
=-.9+.8
=-.1$
and
$n
=a/x
=-.9/(-.1)
=9
$.